# What does following command do sed

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I try to understand what the following sed command will do:

```
sed ‘s/[[:digit:]]+\([[:digit:]]\)/0/g’ myfile
```

Comment: should + be scaped with \ ?

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: @TomFenech Because return 0 result. I tried on a file that contain number, but nothing to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this should be a comment but it's a bit long...

Without any switches (typically `-r`/`-E` depending on your version of sed), this would match a single digit, followed by a plus sign, followed by another digit. It would capture the digit after the plus sign but not use it in the replacement (which seems a bit strange to me).

With extended regular expressions enabled (using one of the switches mentioned above), this would match one or more digits, followed by a single digit in parentheses.

In both cases, any matches would be replaced by 0.

It looks more likely to me that the command is supposed to be run in extended mode but I'm not aware of any versions of sed where this is enabled by default, so the command looks like it's probably broken.

I'm also suspicious about the quotes surrounding the command `‘` as they don't appear to be normal single quotes `'` - this may be causing you a problem as well...

In any case, it would help us to help you if you provided a sample of your input and explained what you were trying to do, rather than just posting a random sed command as a question :)

Comment: Exactly, you're right. That's what I thought also.Have tried with Diff numbers, the only ones who have been replaced were single number + single number.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it on input containing patterns like 12(5) and seeing what it does.  In general, `s/pattern/something/g` searches and replaces every instance of *pattern* with *something*.

Comment: Nothing happening. Only change the number like that  2+23 changes to 03 and 12+4 changes to 10, and 5+5 changes to 0, and 5-5 return as 5-5. 

I think this changes single number + single number to 0.  But how 12+4 became 10?